# Confidence intervals for survival times using survfit function in R for multiple new data points

Tags: r, prediction, confidence-interval, cox-regression

I think the solution to this is probably quite straight forward but I cannot figure it out.

I have fitted a cox proportional hazards model to a data set. I want to make absolute risk predictions for new data points, as would be done in a risk prediction model. For example, P(T>t) where T is the time until an event of interest.

Mathematically I understand this process. The cumulative hazard function must be estimated first, one example of a formula for doing this can be found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46532/cox-baseline-hazard

The survival function is then a simple function of the cumulative hazard function,  **S(t)=exp⁡(−H(t))**, formula can be found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58046/proof-of-relationship-between-hazard-rate-probability-density-survival-functio

After fitting a cox proportional hazards model, called fit1, this can all be done using the *survfit* and *summary* functions in R, for a new data point, *newdata*:

```
newdata1 = data.frame(x1=0,x2=3,x3=5)

summary(survfit(fit1, newdata, type="aalen",se.fit = TRUE, conf.int = 0.95),times=50)
```

This gives P(T>50), and the following output:

```
 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
   50  14462    3216    0.835 0.00631        0.823        0.848
```

Crucially this gives an upper and lower CI for the survival probability. Now if I want to do this for multiple data points, so I define:

```
newdata1 = data.frame(x1=0,x2=3,x3=5)
newdata2 = data.frame(x1=1,x2=1,x3=2)

newdata=rbind(newdata1,newdata2)

summary(survfit(fit1, newdata, type="kalb",se.fit = TRUE, conf.int = 0.95),times=50)
```

I get the following output:

```
time n.risk n.event survival1 survival2
  50  14462    3216     0.835     0.822
```

It gives the survival probability for each patient, but not the associated confidence intervals. This is despite confidence intervals being requested by conf.int=0.95.

So the questions is: **How can I get confidence intervals around the survival probabilities when getting predicted survival probabilities for more than one data point?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is not exactly the output of function, rather a summary of output where different behaviors are defined for different numbers of rows in the `newdata`. 
You can see that from the following example

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age, data=ovarian) 
(CI_summary1 <- summary(survfit(fit, newdata=data.frame(age=c(60)), type="aalen",se.fit = TRUE, conf.int = 0.95),times=50))
(CI_summary2 <- summary(survfit(fit, newdata=data.frame(age=c(60,70)), type="aalen",se.fit = TRUE, conf.int = 0.95),times=50))
str(CI_summary2)
```

The confidence intervals you are looking for are in `CI_summary2$upper` and `CI_summary2$lower`.

Comment: The _str_ function is particularly helpful here, I see this can be applied to all R objects.

Comment: Yep, it is probably my most frequently used R function other than `<-` :)